# What’s this brick called? Two studs long and has clips on one side

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

It’s two studs long and has two clips with horizontal openings on one side.

[image: two studs long and has the clips on one side]

Answer (score 11):

BrickLink calls it [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 2 U Clips (Horizontal Grip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60470), but it might be the newer [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 2 Open O Clips (Horizontal Grip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60470b) that @Alex politely pointed out. I always have a hard time telling them apart in real life, let alone from photos.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: Could also be a [newer version](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60470b).

Comment: Oops, yes, I should have included the information BrickLink almost threw at me. Thanks!

Comment: The 60470b page has an image that shows the 60470 and 60470b side by side in profile so you can see the difference between the clips.

Comment: I have seen the clips in person, and been able to tell the difference, probably. Even that image doesn't really do much for my understanding, alas. (I also don't know at what point I am supposed to move the comments to chat.)

Comment: The primary difference is squared or rounded ends on the clips, for all the blurry image, this looks like the new one to me. Open O rather than U

Comment: @Separatrix I agree. The angle of the photo is not great, but it does seem like the tips of the clips detach from the surface the piece is lying on. If it were the U, they would lie flat.